# How do I solve this Syntax error: Unexpected token (1:13)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, npm

I was wondering what I did wrong, because my code presists to show on my browser, I am still starting out, so slowly learning by thankfully more skillful individuals on stackoverflow :)

```
Card 1.jsx

Syntax error:() Unexpected token (1:13)

> 1 | import React {component} from 'react';
    |              ^
  2 | import '../Card.css'
  3 | 
  4 | const Card = (props) => (
```

Full Code:

```js
import React {component} from 'react';
import '../Card.css'

const Card = (props) => (
    <div className="card-container">
        <div className ="card">
            <div className ="front">
                <div className="Que">Question</div>
            </div>
            <div classnName ="back">
                <div classnName ="Ans">Answer</div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 )

export default Card
```

Comment: You are missing a comma in between React and {Component}

Comment: In this case, why do you need to specify `{Component}` (and not `{component}`) when you already import `React` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
import React, {component} from 'react';
```

Comment: The error is just about this curly open bracket `{component}`. 
Doc : https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#how-to-follow-along

Answer (score 0):

Just : `import React from 'react';`